# Can I trap a "send" event on O365 Outlook web

Tags: outlook, office365

I have a requirement to be able to prompt the user when they send an email from Outlook:

- If there is an attachment then ask then a question about the attachment
- confirm yes / no
- cancel appropriately.

In Outlook on premises I can do that through a client Add-In.

The problem is now the customer wants to go to O365 and the functionality needs to be available through the Outlook web client and mobile OWA.

I cannot find any way to trigger an O365 Add-In automatically for outlook web and/or get any hooks into the Send functionality.

How can I trap the send event on O365 Outlook Web?

Any guidance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot trap any events when a message is sent in the current implementation of OWA.

Comment: not the answer I wanted - but I appreciate you taking the time to answer - thanks :)

Comment: It's even difficult to get information about attachments in compose mode (need to do it via EWS).